# options OnClick not working in IE? But working in FF

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I think I need onChange.

```js
function changeFree() {
  var a = document.getElementById("aSelectControl");
  a.options[a.selectedIndex].text = "Available";
}


function changeUnavailable() {
  var a = document.getElementById("aSelectControl");
  a.options[a.selectedIndex].text = "Unavailable";
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option onClick="changeFree()">Available</option>
  <option onClick="changeUnavailable()">Provisonal Booking</option>
  <option onClick="changeUnavailable()">Fully Booked</option>
</select>


<select id="aSelectControl">
  <option>Available</option>
  <option>Provisonal Booking</option>
  <option>Fully Booked</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

IE (<9?) doesn't support onclick on options. Also, users can change the selected option without clicking by using keyboard navigation. You should probably use onchange on the select element instead.

Comment: Yes IE8. I haven't checked IE9. I will try to use onchange. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is to add an 'onChange' event to the selectbox. This call a function which reads the selected value and decides about the behavior.

What exactly is your goal with your source code?